# Create new column based on index of values in another sorted list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in pandas

```
val1 val2 val3 time 
 a    b    c    0       
 d    e    f    5
 g    h    i    7
 j    k    l    4
 c    a    q    9
 m    e    t    2
 g    n    y    1
 v    k    l    0
```

and `timesteps = [0, 3, 8`]

And I want to create a new column that is the the maximal value of an elemet from `timesteps` that is lower than `row["time"]`
For example, here the new column will be `[0,3,3,3,8,0,0,0]`

What is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 4):

Using [`pd.cut()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.cut.html):

```
timesteps = [0, 3, 8]
bins=timesteps+[df.time.max()]
#[0, 3, 8, 9]
pd.cut(df.time,bins=bins,labels=timesteps,include_lowest=True)
```

---

```
0    0
1    3
2    3
3    3
4    8
5    0
6    0
7    0
```

Comment: Sometime I get the error `"Bin edges must be unique: array([3.11141521e+09, 3.11141521e+09, 3.11141521e+09, 3.11141521e+09]"`
When using `duplicates="drop"` I get the error:  `Bin labels must be one fewer than the number of bin edges`
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this method.

```
from pandas import Series,DataFrame
import pandas as pd
import random
df = DataFrame({
    'val1': ['a','d','g','j','c','m','g','v'],
    'val2':['b','e','h','k','a','e','n','k'],
    'val3':['c','f','i','l','q','t','y','l'],
    'time':[0,5,7,4,9,2,1,0]})
id = df['time'].idxmax()
max = df['time'][id]
df['timesteps'] = df.apply(lambda x: random.randint(0,max-1),axis = 1)
```